# Characteristic and minimal polynomials of linear transformation on space of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd appreciate checking/helping with the following

We define

$$S:M_3(\Bbb R)\to M_3(\Bbb R)\;,\;\;S(A)=\frac{3A+A^t}2$$

with the usual inner product on the space ($\;\langle A,B\rangle:=tr.(AB^t)\;$)

We're asked to answer whether (1) $\;S\;$ is unitary, (2) what are the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $\;S\;$ .

My work: for

$$E_{12}=(e_{ij})\in M_3(\Bbb R)\;,\;\;e_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;(ij)= (12)\\0&,\;\;(ij)\neq(12)\end{cases}$$

I got that

$$S(E_{12})=\frac12\left(3E_{12}+E_{12}^t\right)=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac32&0\\\frac12&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\implies$$

$$||S(E_{12})||^2=tr.(S(E_{12})(S(E_{12}))^t)=tr.\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac32&0\\\frac12&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac12&0\\\frac32&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\right)=$$
$$=tr.\begin{pmatrix}\frac94&0&0\\0&\frac14&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=\frac52$$

and on the other hand

$$||E_{12}||=tr.\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=2$$

so the map isn't unitary.

Now, given as a hint we get $\;S^2\in \text{Span}\,\{I,S\}\;$ , and indeed

$$S^2(A)=\frac12S(3A+A^t)=\frac12\frac12(3(3A+A^t)+(3A+A^t)^t)=\frac14(10A+6A^t)=$$

$$=\frac52A+\frac32A^t=3\left[\frac12(3A+A^t)\right]-2A=3S(A)-2I(A)$$

and from here

$$S^2-3S+2I=0\implies x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)=\text{the minimal polynomial of}\;\;S$$

**My problem:** How to get  the characteristic polynomial?! It must be a degree nine polynomial and I can't se how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$ then
$$S(A)=A\iff A=-A^t\iff A\in\mathcal{AS}_n(\Bbb R) $$
and since 
$$\dim \mathcal{AS}_n(\Bbb R)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}:=\alpha_n$$
hence the multiplicity of $1$ is $\alpha_n$ and if $A$ an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $2$ then
$$S(A)=2A\iff A\in\mathcal{S}_n(\Bbb R)$$
and 
$$\dim \mathcal{S}_n(\Bbb R)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}:=\beta_n$$
hence the multiplicity of $2$ is $\beta_n$.
Finally
$$\chi_S(x)=(x-1)^{\alpha_n}(x-2)^{\beta_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is $\;\mathcal AS_n(\Bbb R\;$ ? The subspace of anti-symmetric matrices?

Comment: Yes it's this subspace!

Comment: Very nice answer. +1

Comment: Then in the Jordan canonical Form we have a Jordan block of size $\;\alpha_n\;$ for $\;\lambda=1\;$ , and one Jordan block of size $\;\beta_n\;$ for $\;\lambda =2\;$ ,right?

Comment: No @Timbuc: as the operator is diagonalizable (why?) all the Jordan blocks have size one!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane , one last question: is the first part that I showed above correct (the "proof" that $\;S\;$ isn't unitary) ? Thank you

Comment: @Timbuc I don't understand exactly what did you do? I know that a matrix $A$ is unitary if $AA^t=I$ which means that the columns of $A$ forms an orthonormal basis. Isn't it?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, that's equivalent with $\;A\;$ being an isometry: $\;||Au||=||u||\;$

Comment: @Timbuc Ah ok so you found a vector ($E_{12}$) such that 
$$||S(E_{12})||\ne ||E_{12}||$$ and then $S$ isn't unitary! OK.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer / Hint:

The roots of the minimal and characteristic polynomials are the same. You need to compute the multiplicity of $2$ and $1$ in the characteristic polynomial.

The minimal polynomial has simple roots so that the map is diagonalizable. It follows that the multiplicities are the dimensions of the associated eigenspaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know the roots are the same, it is precisely their algebraic multiplicy what I can't find.